# My question is about an analogy about the consumer-producer problem in computer science

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, producer-consumer

I have a basic understanding of a producer-consumer problem in a bounded buffer, but I am not able to relate it to this analogy: Describe how a highway off-ramp onto a local road is a good example of a producer/consumer
relationship with a bounded buffer. In particular, discuss how the designers might choose the size
of the off-ramp.

Things I know: (I feel this is just the basics, but anyway)
In a bounded buffer, we need a thread-safe consumer and producer.
A producer can execute only when the buffer is not full.
A consumer can execute only when the buffer is not empty.
At a time either producer can execute or consumer can execute.

I'm assuming the highway to be the producer for vehicles. These vehicles are going to a local road through an off-ramp. Hence off-ramp is the buffer, and the local road is the consumer. Am I taking it in the right way? but I've no idea how to relate it to the size of the off-ramp!

Comment: Hmm, sorry, no.  Feels like homework.

Comment: Do you have a specific question, or are you asking us to do your work?

Comment: Sorry, I'm a programmer. Not a traffic safety engineer.

Comment: @shmosel I'm assuming the highway to be the producer for vehicles. These vehicles are going to a local road through an off-ramp. Hence off-ramp is the buffer, and the local road is the consumer. Am I taking it in the right way? but I've no idea how to relate it with the size of the off-ramp!

Comment: If you know the off-ramp is the buffet, what's the analogy problem? What happens if the buffet is too small? What issues might be caused by the buffer being too big? Where's the confusion?

Answer (score 0):

If the producer is the highway, the off-ramp is the bounded buffer, and the local road is the consumer then you might think of the data throughput as a form of traffic flow.
If the highway feeds the off-ramp faster than vehicles can enter the side street then your off-ramp will fill up. If the highway feeds the off-ramp slower than the vehicles can enter the side street the side street will sometimes have no traffic from the highway. If the off-ramp fills up some of the traffic will either back up onto the highway or will have to use an alternate highway exit.

The producer-consumer pattern has similar behaviors. If the producer writes data to the bounded buffer faster than the consumer reads data from the bounded buffer the buffer will fill. When the buffer fills either the producer must wait for space in the buffer to write new values to the buffer. When the buffer empties the consumer must wait for data to be available in the buffer before the consumer can read from the buffer.

This is where the analogy starts to fail us. Producer-consumer patterns can be blocking in an attempt to ensure all data produced by the producer is consumed by the consumer. However, it is also possible to design a producer-consumer pattern that recognizes that the producer will always be faster than the consumer and therefore the consumer will never process all the data produced in a continuous system. In this case the producer must be able to over-write some of the data before the consumer reads the data. This is known as a sampling system. The consumer only reads a sample of the data, not every data value.

An example of a sampling system might be an engine control system. The sensors monitoring cylinder pressure may be able to produce data at a rate of one reading per milisecond, or 1000 times per second, but the engine valve controls may only be able to respond to the cylinder pressure at a rate of 500 times per second. If the bounded buffer were infinitely large the consumer (the valve controls) would always be dealing with very old data, causing the engine to be responding to cylinder pressures from multiple seconds in the past. The engine would be out of control. If, instead, the valve controls only read the most recent data, ignoring any data between the last reading and the current reading, the engine could maintain proper control. It would never be dealing with stale data.

A producer-consumer using a sampling buffer often only needs a single element buffer. The producer writes to the buffer at its natural rate. The consumer reads the data at its natural rate. With a single element buffer the consumer is guaranteed to only see the most recent value in the buffer. All intermediate values are not even seen by the consumer.